# How to convert stream to download laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
            $stream = fopen('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($response),'r');
            $stat = fstat($stream);
            $size = $stat['size'];

            $type = "video/mp4";
            $start = 0;
            $length = $size;
            $status = 200;

            $headers = ['Content-Type' => $type, 'Content-Length' => $size, 'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes'];

            return response()->stream(
                function() use ($stream, $start, $length) {
                    fseek($stream, $start, SEEK_SET);
                    echo fread($stream, $length);
                    fclose($stream);
                }, $status, $headers
            );
```

the above is working to stream a video
but I need to download the video directly instead...
any suggestions, please

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I used **streamDownload** and its working

```
           return response()->streamDownload(
                function() use ($stream, $start, $length) {
                    fseek($stream, $start, SEEK_SET);
                    echo fread($stream, $length);
                    fclose($stream);
                }, $filename , $headers
            );
```